# Does VIMProbable have register support?

Tags: vim, browser, vi

VIMProbable is a browser that works using vi keys.

Does it have support for storing text in registers?

Comment: There are a couple relevant meta questions which would agree with that stance: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/54/15 http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/7/15

Comment: Alright, that's fine; if you have the rep, please move the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vim but does this person's [article on Vimprobable](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2011/06/26/using-vimprobable/) give information to possibly answer your question? It sounds like text is only yanked to the clipboard, not registers.